# My cocaine refinery can't produce output because my storage is always full of weed. What should I do?

Tags: basement

Once I get a hydroponic plant or a hash ranch, I have a really hard time producing any other type of drug since my storage gets spammed with weed. Is there anything I can do about it besides only using growboxes? Can you disable or sell facilities somehow?

[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

Comment: Link for the game before someone asks: http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-29/?action=preview&uid=5862

Comment: Two things arose for me with this question: A want to make a joke about street corners... And a need to find out what "Ludum Dare" is. I at least got education out of this.

Comment: I have the same problem, i think one needs to find a balance within storage and getting the next drug lab. If they continue developping they should put filters on the storage rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. At a certain point you simply become unable to buy supplies to make any more drugs because your storage rooms are full. Buying more storage rooms will only slightly slow down the inevitable.

There are four types of drugs, but also multiple rooms that are beefed up versions of previous rooms. From my playthroughs basically you want the same number of producers for every drug or one will pile up quickly and make progression impossible. I imagine that is how every single playthrough will end no matter what you do, but if you keep your production the same (ie. one of every of the lowest level buildings) you will be in a far better shape.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the people that will come pick up the drugs will start buying in a bigger quantity. Thats what im experiencing. There is no way to sell or stop work in your grew boxes in the web version.

The way to get more of the other stuff is just to add more and faster producing modules of the other products.